# Rendering components dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a Ionic dynamic page where going to be rendered two components. For exemple:

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
       book_code: 237
       description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...."
       id: 4
       name: "Book 4"
       page_id: 1
       price: 404
       read_status: "Complete"
    },
    {
       description: "This is a description."
       id: 0
       name: "Movie 0"
       page_id: 2
    }
 ]
```

Where `page_id` is the param for load the component.

In my TS class, I'm doing this:

```
  loadComponents(){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
      this.componentsToLoad.push(this.getComponent(this.items[i]));
    }
    console.log(this.componentsToLoad);
  }

  getComponent(item: any){
    let klass = this.avaliableComponents[item['page_id']];
    let instance = new klass()
    instance.draw(item);
    return klass; // If I return 'instance', i get 'No component factory found for [object Object]' error.
  }
```

The method `draw` do this:

```
draw(data: any) {
    this.movie.id = data['id'];
    this.movie.name = data['name'];
    this.movie.pageId = data['page_id'];
    this.movie.description = data['description'];
}
```

PS: For each class (Movie and Book) there are a specific implementation.

In my page, the components are rendering right but the values are not right, the values are blank.

I try to `console.log` the method `draw` and i saw that the values are setted right.

I'm rendering the components like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let component of componentsToLoad" style="background-color: white;">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: First you did declare loadComponents() and inside it there is a loop, which in each time is declaring getComponent(item) and inside it , its's accessing klass(), so data will be gotten successfully but for the next loop it will be zerowized or cleared, try to declare the variables under exports and use them in the get component.

Comment: Did you try to follow this guide? from angular.io - https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @benshabatnoam I follow this guide and it works, thanks.

Comment: Good news, thanks for the update. consider deleting this question as it will never be answered...